# Coding sum of products for all possible combinations

Tags: r, excel-formula, sas

Dear stackoverflow problem-solvers,

I have the following equation to code (I was trying in Excel, but I'm open to a R/SAS solution):
[image: Image of the equation/can't directly post the image.]

I am having trouble with the last summation. If I'm not mistaken, it's the sum of all possible product in my V. In my case, r is always 1, so we can forget that part. My data is presently in the form of an Excel file, will all V in a column. As I have 16 V, I would like to avoid doing all the combinations by hand.

Thanks for helping a desesperate biologist

Just adding, I haven't wrote anything about what I tried, because I really don't know how to handle the problem or how to search for that information (lack of knowing the english word in mathematic...)

Comment: Sounds like a vector product to me (multiply Vj by a transposed Vk).

Comment: If it regards all possible combinations, then I guess the second "Sigma" is something like `sum(combn(mydata$V, 2, function(x) prod(sqrt(x))))`? "m" must be `length(mydata$V)` and the first "Sigma" just a `sum(mydata$V)`? ("mydata" is what you'll have loaded from Excel to R)

Comment: in case all the r are equal to 1, `sqrt(v) %*% sqrt(v)/m^2`

Comment: Thanks alexis_laz, it does work and I do understand the code !

Comment: @agstudy Doesn't that ignore the summation to the right of the plus sign?

Answer (score 2):

R-solution advice: Assuming that all the r values are equal to 1, the value in the final set of parentheses can be calculated with

```
sum(sqrt(v) %*% t(sqrt(v)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a SAS / SQL solution:

```
option linesize = 150;

data have;
    do i = 1 to 16;
        v = ranuni(1);
        output;
    end;
run;

proc sql noprint _method _tree;
    select (sum1 + sum2)* m**(-2) into :result from
        (
            select sum(sqrt(a.v) * sqrt(b.v)) as sum1
                from have as a, have as b
                where a.i ne b.i
        ),  
        (
            select sum(v) as sum2, count(v) as m
                from have
        ) ;
quit; 

%put V_y = &result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel using matrix multiplication, with your values in A1:A16:

```
=SUM(SQRT(MMULT(A1:A16,TRANSPOSE(A1:A16))))/(count(A1:A16)^2)
```

Entered as an array formula (ctrl-shift-enter)